# FullCalendar 3.9.0 - AgendaWeek is plotting the event in a wrong date and time

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                events: [
                    {
                        title: 'Event 1',
                        start: '2023-04-17T04:00:00',
                        end: '2023-04-17T08:00:00',
                        backgroundColor: 'red' // Set background color for Event 1
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Event 2',
                        start: '2023-04-18T02:30:00',
                        end: '2023-04-18T10:00:00',
                        backgroundColor: 'green' // Set background color for Event 2
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Event 3',
                        start: '2023-04-17T09:00:00',
                        end: '2023-04-17T11:30:00',
                        backgroundColor: 'blue' // Set background color for Event 3
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="calendar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the output
[image]
I notice that "Event 3" is plotted incorrectly. It is plotted at the date 4/18 and the start time is 2:30AM.

If you check my `events` data, "Event 3" should be ploitted at 04/17 and start time should be 09:00AM.

Why is that? I've been banging my head about this issue.

Your help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/OJVMPVy (that's using v3.10.2...I doubt it makes much difference but you could upgrade just in case).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I resolved this one by updating my FullCalendar version into v3.10.2.

Comment: No worries. You should consider a major version upgrade too because v3 is very outdated now.